# iOS 8 shows popup for basic auth on 401 for OAuth

Tags: javascript, ios, oauth-2.0

I have a JavaScript app that is posting to an in-house API, the API is OAuth2 and we're including the access token in the header of the requests:

```
Authorization:Bearer 2267a056aab4100228a046267bfdfef6c2d73aaec66403eddf854914fa829310
```

and when we try to post to the api with an expired token we return a 401 (as we should) with this header:

```
WWW-Authenticate:OAuth realm='OAuth API', error='expired_token'
```

but on iOS this is triggering the native "basic auth" popup asking for a username and password which is not only wrong (I'm pretty sure) but also confusing to our users.

Is there a way to have iOS not do this popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to match an Error Response for `invalid grant` and allow a 400 Error response.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-5.2

> invalid_grant - The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization
> code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
> invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
> URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
> another client.

410 Gone doesn't really work as a response , as the token is still there, it is merely expired or invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use

> 410 Gone

The requested resource is no longer available at the server and no forwarding
address is known. This condition is expected to be considered permanent.

Comment: That doesnt follow spec "the authorization server MUST respond with an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized)" [oauth2 spec](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749)

Comment: That doesn't apply to refresh tokens or expired tokens.  View section 5.2.  Error Response of the docs.